# PHP framework that allows both getRow and getRows?

Tags: php, database, frameworks

I downloaded AlegroCart from https://code.google.com/p/alegrocart/ and I am trying to figure out which database framework is being used.

One of the methods being used is `getRow`:

```
$result = $this->database->getRow("select order_reference, total from order_google where order_number = '" . $orderNumber . "'");
```

but there is also a call to `getRows`:

```
$result = $this->database->getRows("select * from zone_to_geo_zone where geo_zone_id = '"  ...
```

Does any one know which framework allows these two calls? I see that Pear framework has getRow but not getRows.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a framework but it seems like it's just some piece of (easy) code directly written by alegrocart :

```
function getRow($sql) {
    $this->query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);
    mysql_free_result($this->result);
    return $row;
}

function getRows($sql) {
    if (func_num_args()) { $this->query(implode(func_get_args(), ', ')); }
    else { $this->query($sql); }

    $rows = array();

    while (is_resource($this->result) && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result)) { $rows[] = $row; }
    if(is_resource($this->result)){
         mysql_free_result($this->result);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

https://code.google.com/p/alegrocart/source/browse/trunk/AlegroCart/upload/library/database/database.php